# How can I pass a password from a bash script to aptitude for installing mysql?

Tags: mysql, bash, ubuntu, installation, debian

I am writing a simple bash script to install MySQL on Ubuntu.

```
#!/bin/bash
apt-get update

# Install MySQL5 
aptitude -y install mysql-server mysql-client libmysqlclient15-dev
```

However MySQL prompts for a password and confirmation. How do I pass along a root password. Is there an echo I can use?

Answer (score 14):

This is so much easier ..

[install mysql on ubuntu without password prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739645/install-mysql-on-ubuntu-without-password-prompt)

```
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server-5.1 mysql-server/root_password password your_password'
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server-5.1 mysql-server/root_password_again password your_password'
sudo apt-get -y install mysql-server
```

If your shell doesn't support `here-strings` (zsh, ksh93 and bash support them), use:

```
echo ... | sudo debconf-set-selections
```

Comment: This is actually the recommended way to do this. Expect scripts or waiting / sleeping are just kludges which will break in the most unfortunate moments.

Comment: I couldn't find documentation for what setting names I needed to overwrite. But I installed the package interactively once and used `sudo debconf-show MyPkg` to list out the variables that were set. Looking at that list, it was pretty obvious what the two password variable names were for my package.

Answer (score 12):

Thank you for the tip on expect. I couldn't find anything by searching Ubuntu admin forums so I went with expect. As you can see by the timestamp of this post, it took me 3 hours to get it working. Here is the code, I hope it can help someone:

```
#!/bin/bash
apt-get update
apt-get install expect

VAR=$(expect -c '
spawn apt-get -y install mysql-server
expect "New password for the MySQL \"root\" user:"
send "PasswordHere\r"
expect "Repeat password for the MySQL \"root\" user:"
send "PasswordHere\r"
expect eof
')

echo "$VAR"

apt-get -y install mysql-client libmysqlclient15-dev   

#For some reason important to restart - otherwise possible errors

/etc/init.d/mysql stop
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Answer (score 7):

This is an excerpt from my setup script for new servers. You should be able to copy it word-for-word except for the password.

You'll need to run this using sudo if you're not already root.

```
#!/bin/bash
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt-get -q -y install mysql-server
echo "Give mysql server time to start up before we try to set a password..."
sleep 5
mysql -uroot -e <<EOSQL "UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('yourpasswordhere') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
EOSQL
echo "Done setting mysql password."
```

Other answers have used the -y which makes apt-get always answer yes to questions. The -q hides some progress indicators so you can send the output to a log. You could also use -qq, which automatically gives you a -y. This is in the man page for apt-get.

The `<<EOSQL` is a bash heredoc syntax for readability.

I got the heredoc part of this solution from this guy: http://padwasabimasala.posterous.com/non-interactive-scripted-mysql-install-on-ubu

The thing to remember with the heredoc is that whitespace before the closing string breaks it. So don't indent that line. Here is a page about the heredoc syntax: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html

Comment: this gives `ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`

Comment: Maybe there was already a root password set? This script doesn't authenticate with a password because mysql didn't have a password already set. You can add the -p to prompt or -p$PASS to provide it on the command line.

Comment: There wasn't, I've tried with a clean VM. I guess mysql doesn't accept a password to be blank.

Comment: My next guess is that you're not really root@localhost depending on how you connect: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712307/mysql-localhost-127-0-0-1

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this is to use the DEBIAN_FRONTEND environment variable and the aptitude -q and -y flags:

```
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive aptitude install -q -y mysql-server
```

Or more generically, assuming sudo password has been catered for some-how:

```
#!/bin/bash
INSTALLER_LOG=/var/log/my-installer.log

installnoninteractive(){
  sudo bash -c "DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive aptitude install -q -y $* >> $INSTALLER_LOG"
}

installnoninteractive mysql-server
```

Comment: I tried the `expect` approach, but kept running into subtle quoting issues. The `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` trick was exactly what I was looking for. Follow it with a `mysqladmin -u root password YOUR_DB_PASSWORD` and you're home in a jiffy.

Comment: +1 for something that actually works on clean insatll of ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 3):

This script was successful when launched as superuser:

```
#!/bin/bash

export temp_mysql_password="**********"
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive 

debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password $temp_mysql_password"
debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password $temp_mysql_password"
debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server-5.6 mysql-server/root_password password $temp_mysql_password"
debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server-5.6 mysql-server/root_password_again password $temp_mysql_password"

apt-get update
apt-get -y upgrade
apt-get -y install mysql-server
```

Comment: Works perfectly... Only I need to change the mysql-server version to 5.7 as It depends on the Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 2):

look into using [expect](http://expect.nist.gov/)

It can be used to automate most interactive sessions, although I wouldn't use a root password

Answer (score 1):

Expect is probably overkill.  Look on one of the Debian or Ubuntu admin forums -- things like FAI et al have long used preseeding for debconf questions.  You should be able to use that here too.

Lastly, you could probably also use apt-get itself or other frontends.