# Install MySQL on Ubuntu without a password prompt

Tags: mysql, bash, ubuntu, apt

How do I write a script to install MySQL server on Ubuntu?

`sudo apt-get install mysql` will install, but it will also ask for a password to be entered in the console.

How do I do this in a non-interactive way? That is, write a script that can provide the password?

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get install mysql  # To install MySQL server

# How to write script for assigning password to MySQL root user
# End
```

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202347/how-can-i-pass-a-password-from-a-bash-script-to-aptitude-for-installing-mysql

Answer (score 438, accepted):

```
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password your_password'
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password your_password'
sudo apt-get -y install mysql-server
```

For specific versions, such as `mysql-server-5.6`, you'll need to specify the version in like this:

```
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server-5.6 mysql-server/root_password password your_password'
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server-5.6 mysql-server/root_password_again password your_password'
sudo apt-get -y install mysql-server-5.6
```

For mysql-community-server, the keys are slightly different:

```
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/root-pass password your_password'
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/re-root-pass password your_password'
sudo apt-get -y install mysql-community-server
```

Replace your_password with the desired root password. (it seems your_password can also be left blank for a blank root password.)

If you writing a script then your shell may be not bash but dash/ash or some basic unix shell. These shells, unlike *zsh*, *ksh93* and *bash*, doesn't support *here-strings* `<<<`. So you should use:

```
echo ... | sudo debconf-set-selections
```

Or a more readable print of multiline strings:

```
cat << EOF | sudo debconf-set-selections
mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password your_password
mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password your_password
EOF
```

You can check with `debconf-get-selections` command:

```
$ sudo debconf-get-selections | grep ^mysql
mysql-server    mysql-server/root_password_again    password    your_password
mysql-server    mysql-server/root_password  password    your_password
```

Comment: Make sure to change the `mysql-server-5.1` part to the current mysql version!

Comment: I used this with capistrano but had to change the shell form sh to bash using the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747759/how-do-i-set-the-shell-to-bash-for-run-in-capistrano

Comment: Running `echo ... | sudo ...` is bad, since it will leave the password in the shell history of the unprivileged user. There are ways around this though, of course.

Comment: In fact, doesn't using here-strings give you the same vulnerability? This is a case where using `sudo -i` and then running debconf-set-selections directly from the root prompt is safer. Or you can go a really convoluted way round to avoid that but is also safe.

Comment: This Answer translates to MariaDB as follows by replacing `mysql-server-<version>` with `maria-db-<server>`. The following occurency of `mysql-server/` **remains untouched**

Comment: -<version> part is unnecessary - works like a charm for me, and is more generic without that.

Comment: This doesn't work for me if I want to keep a blank password on a dev box.

Comment: This works fine with after ``sudo apt-get install debconf-utils``

Comment: Commenting here for future self. In my case, I had to use the 'echo' method while using a bamboo instance for automating deployments and general git-merge-fu.

Comment: This didn't initally work for me, but it did work after performing a
sudo apt-get update; apt-get -y upgrade

Comment: This is great! It works and thanks. But how did you discover this?

Comment: @Lukx for MariaDB, the package is mariadb-server, not maria-db-server. Thanks for the note anyway.

Comment: I tried `sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password root'` and am getting the error message: `sh: 2: Syntax error: redirection unexpected`

Comment: Try this instead and let us know if it works: `printf 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password your_password' | sudo debconf-set-selection`
 and `printf 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password your_password' | sudo debconf-set-selection`

Comment: @DimitreRadoulov Yes, that worked - I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 :) Thanks. Note that there is a typo in your comment, "s" is missing at the ends of `debconf-set-selections`.

Comment: Should these be unset in some way afterwards for safety?

Comment: Hi @janw, yes, see [this post](http://serverfault.com/questions/332459/how-do-i-delete-values-from-the-debconf-database).

Comment: Just FYI, because I got stuck on this for amlost an hour: You have to actually set a password. An empty string will not work! It has to be _something_.

Comment: I don't know why this didn't worked for me. I tried every way possible described above and in other answers but the password always stays empty, I even check the deb-set-selections value and they are there correctly. I ended up doing something like this, to first connect using a default file and then changing the password: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46955693/cant-properly-set-mysql-password-from-external-bash-script . Ps: I'm installing mysql in Circleci, machine type executor, so no docker.

Comment: I don't know why I only started having this problem in 2021. Suddenly a Vagrant script started getting the prompt when it never did before.

Answer (score 244):

This should do the trick

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
sudo -E apt-get -q -y install mysql-server
```

Of course, it leaves you with a blank root password - so you'll want to run something like

```
mysqladmin -u root password mysecretpasswordgoeshere
```

Afterwards to add a password to the account.

Comment: Tested and working in new Ubuntu 12.04 instance with MySQL 5.5

Comment: This did not work for me with Azure platform image of Ubunutu 12.04 LTS 64-bit and MySQL 5.5

Comment: Worked for me on 12.04 whereas the accepted answer left me unable to log in as root. Couldn't guess the password

Comment: This left me unable to log in as root because I couldn't guess the password. I put the code in a bash file and executed. Using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: seems to work in a Dockerfile with `ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive` but not in a bash (12.04)

Comment: If you are installing with sudo, use -E so that the environment variable is passed along.  Eg. sudo -E apt-get -q -y install mysql-server.

Comment: You can also add the env variable directly into the command (without polluting the external environment) by prepending it - `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install mysql-server`

Comment: After doing `apt-get update` it worked for me on `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS` and `mysql-server-5.5`

Comment: The mysql password will be stored in a bash log when done this way.

Comment: @DutGRIFF add a space before the command, and it won't appear in the log.

Comment: Worked for me on Debian 8.2--I combined from @PatrickCullen and @yoniLavi to get `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive sudo -E apt-get -q -y install mysql-server`--worked like a charm!

Comment: This doesn't work. mysqladmin doesn't return an error, but it doesn't seem to successfully set the password either.

Comment: I have not been able to get this method to work with Ubuntu 16.04 and mysql-server 5.7. It did, however, work up until I moved to 16.04.

Comment: You can also do `sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install mysql-server`, sudo knows how to deal with environment variable assignements that are passed to it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the different command-line options are and what the purpose is in this context?

Comment: Working on docker? prefer Dimitre's answer.

Answer (score 31):

Another way to make it work:

```
echo "mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server/root_password password root" | debconf-set-selections
echo "mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server/root_password_again password root" | debconf-set-selections
apt-get -y install mysql-server-5.5
```

Note that this simply sets the password to "root". I could not get it to set a blank password using simple quotes `''`, but this solution was sufficient for me.

Based on a solution [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=981801).

Comment: _echo 'mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server/root_password password ' | sudo debconf-set-selections_ works to specify blank password for me.

Comment: @TsuneoYoshioka Doesn't work for me. If I put two spaces at the end it sets my password to a single space. With one space it still tries to give the prompt and then screws up the installation.

Comment: The solution is better because it works in plain UNIX shell or dash

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y mysql-server

sudo mysql -h127.0.0.1 -P3306 -uroot -e"UPDATE mysql.user SET password = PASSWORD('yourpassword') WHERE user = 'root'"
```

Comment: Thanks! defining variables outside sudo always gets me.