# How do I set the shell to bash for run in Capistrano?

Tags: bash, rvm, capistrano

How can I set the shell in the Capistrano run command to use bash instead of sh?
I am trying to install RVM and I need to execute the command:

```
run "bash < <(curl -L http://bit.ly/rvm-install-system-wide)"
```

as in:

```
task :install_rvm, :roles => :server do
  apps = %w(bison openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev     libyaml-dev sqlite3 libsqlite3-0 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf subversion libcurl4-openssl-dev)
  apt.install( {:base => apps}, :stable )
  run "bash < <(curl -L http://bit.ly/rvm-install-system-wide)"
  run "rvm install 1.9.2".sh
  run "rvm use 1.9.2@global"
  run "gem install awesome_print map_by_method wirble bundler builder pg cheat"
  run "gem install -v2.1.2 builder"
  # modify .bashrc
end
```

But I just can't seem to get it to work because Capistrano is executing:

```
"sh -c 'bash < <(curl -L http://bit.ly/rvm-install-system-wide)'" on ubuntu@ec2...
```

I see in the Capistrano gem the command.rb file has some code like

```
shell = "#{options[:shell] || "sh"} -c"
```

but it is unclear to me how to pass `options[:shell]` to the task

Comment: It looks like it's executing `bash` via `sh -c `bash ...``.  How does that not meet your requirements?  (Disclaimer: I know nothing about Capistrano.)

Answer (score 34):

set :shell is not working, but that works:

`default_run_options[:shell] = '/bin/bash'`

Comment: Note that for rvm, you may need `/bin/bash --login`

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like you need the [rvm-capistrano](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm-capistrano) gem. Another option would be to use the mechanism used by rvm-capistrano, that is:

```
set :default_shell, '/bin/bash -l'
```

Comment: great, helped me much on CentOs target system for deployment

Comment: This worked well for me in a bind on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `:shell` variable.

```
set :shell, '/usr/bin/bash'
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Capistrano, shell can only be changed with `default_run_options`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following syntax:

```
execute "bash -c '<command>'"
```

It is especially useful for setting environment with --login switch, for example:

```
execute "bash --login -c 'rvm use 1.9.2'"
```

...and it also works in Capistrano 3.x...!

Be sure to wrap the command in single quotes so that it is passed to `bash` as a single argument, and so that pathname expansion (globbing), parameter expansion and so on are not performed too early.