# Resetting mysql root password from python-fabric without prompt

Tags: python, mysql, linux, centos, fabric

I'm trying to automate a deployment of an application by Python-fabric. The installation has to be done **without** any human intervention.

In CentOS 6.4 server the if i install mysql through

```
$yum install mysql-server
```

Then mysql is installed with a NULL password.

Now the problem is when i reset the `mysql` root password from fabric by issuing :

```
run("mysqladmin -u %s -p password %s " % ('root','khd5u8bWN'))
```

It prompts for a password (which is NULL) and i have to press the return key to proceed.

Now as i want to achieve "full" automation, i want this "pressing enter" automatically. How can i achieve this in python-fabric?

Answer (score 1):

When a mysql password is empty you can login to that account by omitting the `-p` option.  So change your run command to:

`run("mysqladmin -u %s password %s " % ('root','khd5u8bWN'))`

Answer (score 0):

You could either set the environment variable `password` in the `env` `dict` (**""** should work if the password is no password) or invoke `fab` with the `-I <pwd>` option.

I generally use the latter option, since it's code agnostic.

**Edit in response to OP's comment:**

Try switching from using `run` to `sudo` to run the command (while still using one of the methods above).

**Edit 2 in response to OP's follow-up comment:**

I'm pretty sure `sudo` is the key here, based on the info provided, but perhaps with certain arguments set. See http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.sudo

**Edit 3 in response to add'l OP follow-up comment:**

Re: it being the `mysql` root password and not an OS password, this may provide some food for thought: [install mysql on ubuntu without password prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739645/install-mysql-on-ubuntu-without-password-prompt)

Comment: I've invoked `fab -I'' -H host command`, but it still prompts for password when resetting mysql root password

Comment: Edited answer w/ response.

Comment: Well still prompting for password :(

Comment: Perhaps you need to specify the `user` arg in the call to `sudo`?

Comment: The password prompt is not for the linux user password. Its the mysql root password. Not sure if its gonna work here. The ssh connection is "keybased" passwordless login. So no linux user password is prompted.