# Can't properly set MySQL password from external bash script

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, ubuntu, debconf

I have two scripts - The main one that does a few different things and calls the second script, and the second script that installs MySQL.

From my main script I do something like this:

```
...

read -p "Set the password for the database [min. 4 characters]: " MPASS

# Install MySQL
path/to/setup-mysql.sh "$MPASS"

mysql --user="root" --password=${MPASS} -e "GRANT ALL ON *.* TO root@'${IPADDRESS}' IDENTIFIED BY '${MPASS}';"
mysql --user="root" --password=${MPASS} -e "GRANT ALL ON *.* TO root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '${MPASS}';"
service mysql restart

mysql --user="root" --password=${MPASS} -e "SET GLOBAL validate_password_policy = 'LOW'; SET GLOBAL validate_password_length = 4; CREATE USER 'johndoe'@'${IPADDRESS}' IDENTIFIED BY '${MPASS}';"
mysql --user="root" --password=${MPASS} -e "GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'johndoe'@'${IPADDRESS}' IDENTIFIED BY '${MPASS}' WITH GRANT OPTION;"
mysql --user="root" --password=${MPASS} -e "GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'johndoe'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '${MPASS}' WITH GRANT OPTION;"
mysql --user="root" --password=${MPASS} -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
```

And `setup-mysql.sh` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/data-dir select ''"
debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/root-pass password ${1}"
debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/re-root-pass password ${1}"

apt-get install -y mysql-server

# Start mysql on boot
update-rc.d mysql defaults

# Configure Password Expiration
echo "default_password_lifetime = 0" >> /etc/mysql/my.cnf

# Configure Access Permissions For Root
sed -i '/^bind-address/s/bind-address.*=.*/bind-address = */' /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

To me this looks like it should work, however, when bash executes this line:

```
mysql --user="root" --password=${MPASS} -e "GRANT ALL ON *.* TO root@'${IPADDRESS}' IDENTIFIED BY '${MPASS}';"
```

It says that the password is wrong. When I try logging in manually it wont work. And when I skip the password field (`mysql -u root`) it works. So the password is not being set at all.

Also, when I do `echo $1` in `setup-mysql.sh`, it properly shows what `MPASS` contains.

Why isn't `debconf-set-selections` setting the password properly for my MySQL installation. I'm really confused here.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are writing a MySQL post-installation initialization shell script.

In my personal opinion: **change your shell script design method.**

In your script, you use `mysql --user="root" --password=${MPASS}` prompt error info. You could use mysql paramater **`--defaults-file`**, write mysql login user `root` and corresponding password into a temp file like

```
[client]
user=root
password=YOURPASSWORD
```

suppose file path is `/tmp/mysql.cnf` (assign variable `mysql_my_cnf`)

Then use `mysql --defaults-file="$mysql_my_cnf"` login, it will login successfully.

Assign a variable to `mysql --defaults-file="$mysql_my_cnf"`, such as `mysql_command`

#### Old method

```
mysql --user="root" --password=${MPASS} -e "GRANT ALL ON *.* TO root@'${IPADDRESS}' IDENTIFIED BY '${MPASS}';"
```

#### New method

```
${mysql_command} -e "GRANT ALL ON *.* TO root@'${IPADDRESS}' IDENTIFIED BY '${MPASS}';"
```

You can try it.

### PS

I wrote a [MySQL and its variants installation and initialization shell script](https://github.com/MaxdSre/axd-ShellScript/blob/master/assets/software/MySQLVariants.sh), it may be helpful for you.