# How can I pass the input from a PHP script to another script?

Tags: php, shell, command-line

I'm trying to make a PHP script that automates installation of linux web servers.

I'm currently stuck at this part:

When I'm installing the MySQL server it will open its own screen and it will ask me for the root password.

I know how to save the password in a variable but how can I make that MySQL screen use that variable?

This is what I have so far:

```php
<?php
$_fp = fopen("php://stdin", "r"); 
echo 'Input mysql root password: '; 
$rootpswd = trim(fgets(STDIN));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739645/install-mysql-on-ubuntu-without-a-password-prompt

Comment: Check: https://gist.github.com/sheikhwaqas/9088872

Comment: Notice the part where I ask how to do that in php, not bash.

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing with apt-get , try adding the -y parameter. Then the root password should be empty.
Errata: /etc/my.cnf only tells the mysql tool which default password to use.