# Bash to expect and back again

Tags: bash, ubuntu-16.04, expect

I am creating a script to setup a series of computers. One of the apps to install is a mysql database. The bash script will call

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

The expect script will have to respond to the questions that are output in sequence from this command, answers will be hardcoded and will be the same for all.

Questions and responses are

```
Enter current password for root (enter for none): Just press the Enter
Set root password? [Y/n]: Y
New password: Enter password
Re-enter new password: Repeat password
Remove anonymous users? [Y/n]: Y
Disallow root login remotely? [Y/n]: Y
Remove test database and access to it? [Y/n]:  Y
Reload privilege tables now? [Y/n]:  Y
```

Comment: [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. Please show your coding efforts.

Comment: If this is a Debian-based platform, the proper solution is a debconf preseed file with the replies to the prompts. Other professional environments offer something similar.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 lts

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739645/install-mysql-on-ubuntu-without-a-password-prompt

Comment: take a look at [*sexpect*](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to try it first without `expect`:

```
echo -e '\nY\nfoobar\nfoobar\nY\nY\nY\nY' | sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

Comment: Thanks, was overwhelmed by expect, up until last night i had never used bash either but this worked great!

Comment: As [glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49596694/bash-to-expect-and-back-again/49597187#comment86203054_49597187) suggested, it becomes more readable with a [here-doc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document).