# Install mysql-server with python-apt

Tags: python, mysql

i have a ubuntu server where i'm trying to **install mysql-server** (as well as other software) **with python-apt**

the problem is that at some point is needed to interact with the installer (providing a password). Is it possible to **interact with the installer** using python-apt?

*Example:*

```
import apt
cache = apt.cache.Cache()
cache.update()
pkg = cache['mysql-server']
pkg.mark_install()
cache.commit()
```

*it stalls waitting for user input*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(edited)
managed to make it work following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739645/install-mysql-on-ubuntu-without-a-password-prompt)

```
from subprocess import check_call
command = "debconf-set-selections <<< \"mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password your_password\""
check_call(command, shell=True, executable="bash")
command = "debconf-set-selections <<< \"mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password your_password\""
check_call(command, shell=True, executable="bash")
command = "apt install mysql-server"
check_call(command, shell=True, executable="bash")
```