# Install mysql in ubuntu without any prompt

Tags: mysql, shell, ubuntu, unix

I want to install mysql in ubuntu without any promt for password & yes/no, is their any command which install mysql with default password or without any prompt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install MySQL on Ubuntu without a password prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739645/install-mysql-on-ubuntu-without-a-password-prompt)

Comment: but still these commands are asking for prompt