# Unatttended MySQL 8 community install on Ubuntu 18.04 WSL

Tags: mysql, bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to install MySQL 8 on an Ubuntu (that is a Windows Subsystem for Linux) without any prompts.

I have the following script:

```
apt-key add --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 5072E1F5
echo 'deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-8.0' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list

apt-get update --yes
apt-get install --yes debconf-utils
echo 'mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/root-pass password' | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo 'mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/re-root-pass password' | sudo debconf-set-selections
apt-get install --yes mysql-community-server
```

(partly constructed thanks to the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739645/))

and it appears to work fine, except that it prompts me to select authentication method... I want to pick the mysql_native_password and do so without being prompted interactively.

I'm guessing the solution is another debconf-set-selections setting, but... In addition to asking what is it for this case... Is there a reference of all possible options somewhere?

There's also the issue that apt-get says that a symlink is created for the service, and yet the service isn't created... But that's not really a showstopper, as I'm using WSL merely as a test ground for an actual Ubuntu server, where I'd think this would work... hopefully.

EDIT1: Nevermind the original question... I managed to find an answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457388/how-to-find-out-the-variable-names-for-debconf-set-selections)
 which led to stumble upon [this dockerfile](https://github.com/chasfricke/my-portfolio/blob/master/Dockerfile)

So I ended up adding

```
echo 'mysql-community-server mysql-server/default-auth-override select Use Legacy Authentication Method (Retain MySQL 5.x Compatibility)' | sudo debconf-set-selections
```

is the line I need...

HOWEVER, the other, possibly WSL specific issue remains... that is, no MySQL service is created. I should note that while I have MySQL outside of WSL, the server is turned off, specifically so that the WSL could run.

I get the following output upon the install, near the end:

```
Setting up mysql-community-server (8.0.16-2ubuntu18.04) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
dpkg: error processing package mysql-community-server (--configure):
 installed mysql-community-server package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-community-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And the only thing I can find related to that is suggestions of complete reinstall, but even reinstalling the WSL instance doesn't fix this.

EDIT2: Adding

```
apt-get dist-upgrade --yes --allow-remove-essential --allow-change-held-packages
```

Fixes the above error, and yet despite there not being any errors, the service is still not created.

Answer (score 0):

I sort of fixed the missing mysql service by copying the /etc/init.d/mysql file from another WSL instance (mysql 8 installed through an upgrade) to /etc/init.d

```
sudo service mysql start
```

returns a [fail], but the mysql daemon runs just fine.

Otherwise, I've seen people achieve this more cleanly by installing a lower version from MySQL's repo first, and then upgrade to mysql 8.