# How to install MySQL 5.6 in Ubuntu 18.04(VM)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, packer, packer-builder

I'm using packer to install MySQL 5.6 on an Ubuntu VM. To install it, I'm using the below script.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main' -y
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe' -y
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6 -y
systemctl restart mysql
```

However, the installer kept prompting for a password. Is there any way to pass the password in the script since it's installed within a VM? I'm stuck in this situation.

[error-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOabQ.png)

Comment: They ask you to set a password for the root user :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install MySQL on Ubuntu without a password prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739645/install-mysql-on-ubuntu-without-a-password-prompt)

Comment: Is there a way I can pass that password in the command itself