# Enter commands at the right time in a bash script

Tags: bash

I have a bash script, that runs a few commands. These commands take input, and I'd like to be able to automate this, as the input is always the same.

Is it possible to send these lines, one a time, when asked for?

```
Y
{JustPressEnter}
{JustPressEnter}
{JustPressEnter}
yes
APassword
```

The full command is this (actual IP removed)

```
apt-get install ssh-client \
    && mkdir /var/www/.ssh/ \
    && chown www-data:www-data /var/www/.ssh/ \
    && sudo -u www-data ssh-keygen -t rsa \
    && cat /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh root@1.2.3.4 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys' \
    && sudo -u www-data touch /var/www/.ssh/known_hosts \
    && sudo -u www-data ssh-keygen -R 1.2.3.4 \
    && sudo -u www-data ssh-keyscan -H 1.2.3.4 >> /var/www/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two different answers:

- Use `expect` to automate commands. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1203563/240443) shows an example of `expect` being used to automate `apt-get` with password input. [Here](http://www.admin-magazine.com/Articles/Automating-with-Expect-Scripts)'s an article that talks at length about `expect`.
- Write each command in batch mode. [ssh-keygen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30509810/240443) can accept all those things as parameters; `apt-get install -y packagename` will assume "yes" on every prompt. If you write your code right, no keyboard interaction needs to take place.

Comment: Thanks :). I used the `-y` apt-get flag, and managed to sort `ssh-keygen` out using parameters. All I have left to do now is get the password auto-inputted to the ssh command. I'll look at expect and try and get it working with that.